# Crossfilter: Bypass filters on other dimensions

Tags: crossfilter

I use multiple dimensions in a Crossfilter (e.g. dimensions date, category, status). It all works as expected, but I also want to have an id-Dimension for fast retrieving a single data object.

Problem is:

If I filter the idDimension.filter(myId), and at the same time the other filters (which filter out the object with id=myId) are applied, crossfilter won't find the given data object. (Afterwards I reset the idDimension.filter(null)).

Is there a way to bypass all other filters for a single crossfilter query? Or there should be a method to save and restore the current filters.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a filter on a unique value dimension in order to retrieve a single record is really inefficient in Crossfilter. What that will do is remove all records except for the single record from all groups, then add them all back when you remove the filter. This means that your group aggregation addition and subtraction functions will run twice on each of these records, really for no reason at all.

It depends on what your exact need is, but I think a better option is to keep an array of all your records outside of Crossfilter sorted on the ID property and use crossfilter.bisect to find the record, or create a map of all the records keyed on the unique ID (use the ES6 Map if your browser supports it, or use an alternative implementation like d3.map) and use Map.prototype.get() to look up the record. In other words, don't use Crossfilter to